# Handle output parameter of an Oracle stored procedure using C# code

Tags: c#, sql, database, oracle, stored-procedures

I'm using **Oracle** database. I have a table called `Room` and then I made this stored procedure:

```sql
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE RETRIEVEROOM
 (RoomID IN INTEGER, RID_Out OUT INTEGER) 
 AS
 BEGIN
    Select Room.RoomNumber INTO RID_Out 
    From Room 
    Where Room.RoomNumber = RoomID;
 END;
```

So I'm trying to send input and output parameters using **C#** with this code:

```cs
private void loadRooms()
{
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = "RETRIEVEROOM";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("RoomID", 218);  // Here I send the input parameter
            cmd.Parameters.Add("RID_Out", "").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output; 
            cmd.Parameters["RID_Out"].Size = 255; 
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show(cmd.Parameters["RID_Out"].ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

When I try to print the value of `output parameter` in the MessageBox, It prints "RID_Out" not the value of `RID_Out` which should be `218`. **How can I solve this problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess you want to print Value property of the parameter.

```
MessageBox.Show((string)cmd.Parameters["RID_Out"].Value, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
```